# icon overlay in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, file-icons

I'm developing a cocoa application for mac. I want to overlay icon of folder and file with other icon as in SCPlugin defined at http://scplugin.tigris.org/. Even SCPlugin is unable to do this on Mac 10.6.
Any idea how can I overlay icon of file or folder with other icon??

Comment: I'm using an approach for this in which I am getting icon of file as NSImage and then overlaying other image on that icon and assigning that icon to file using setIcon of NSWorkspace.